# 3 digit card codes failing with error E00003 The value XXXXXXX is invalid according to its datatype - The Pattern constraint failed

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

Code below:-

```
public bool AuthorizePayment(string Card_Num, string Exp_Date, string Card_Code, string amount)
{
      //Console.WriteLine("Charge Credit Card Sample");

      ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.RunEnvironment = AuthorizeNet.Environment.SANDBOX;

      // define the merchant information (authentication / transaction id)
      ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.MerchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType()
      {
          name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNetID"],
          ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.transactionKey,
          Item = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNetKey"],
      };

      var creditCard = new creditCardType
      {
          cardNumber = Card_Num,
          expirationDate = Exp_Date,
          cardCode = Card_Code
      };

      //standard api call to retrieve response
      var paymentType = new paymentType { Item = creditCard };

      var transactionType = objInf.Get("x_type") == "AUTH_CAPTURE" ? transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString() : transactionTypeEnum.refundTransaction.ToString();

      var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType
      {
          transactionType = transactionType,
          amount = Convert.ToDecimal(amount),
          payment = paymentType,
      };

      if (objInf.Get("x_invoice_num") != null)
      {
          transactionRequest.order = new orderType { invoiceNumber = objInf.Get("x_invoice_num") };
      }
      if (objInf.Get("x_trans_id") != null)
      {
          transactionRequest.refTransId = objInf.Get("x_trans_id");
      }

      var request = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = transactionRequest };

      // instantiate the controller that will call the service
      var controller = new createTransactionController(request);
      controller.Execute();

      // get the response from the service (errors contained if any)
      var response = controller.GetApiResponse();

      // validate response
      if (response != null)
      {
          //other code
      }
      else
      {
          //other code
      }
  }
```

Most of the code is copy paste from AuthNet site and incase the card code which I am sending to AuthNet is 3 digit then the transaction fails and Api returns null response even though the its clearly mentioned in the API documentation that 3 digit card code is valid. Any help on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this in a sandbox account or a production account? What card number are you using and what card code are you using?

Comment: I am getting the error in Production

Comment: Are you sure is it because of the cardCode ? It might be because of some other fields ? can you try the request in Sandbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening when cardType was AmericanExpress and card code was 3 digit and that is how it should be because Amex cards have a 4 digit code, so seems like the users were entering incorrect data.

The site which I was working on was previously using the AIMs implementation of the AuthNet api. This issue never happened with AIMs so I am guessing Authnet did not have this check of matching the number of digits to its card type in place in AIMs. What we did to solve this problem was that we contacted authnet customer service and as per their suggestion, we stopped sending the card code altogether.

Answer (score 0):

XXXXXXX in the error message gives a clue that Authorize.Net is getting 5 chars, check if your cardCode is wrapped in spaces (e.g. "cardCode":"  123" or " 123 " or "123  ").

Comment: Thanks, but that wasnt the problem in my case.